# Trouble using Session variable in header redirect

Tags: php, session

I am using the following to lock in a location if a user isn't logged in so that I can return to this location once login is successful

```
$_SESSION['returnURL'] = htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], ENT_QUOTES);
```

I am having no luck using this session variable in my header redirect.  The contents of this variable currently is: `/event.php?title=Test&id=16`

```
if($sql->num_rows==1) {
    if (isset($_SESSION['returnURL'])){
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        header("location:$_SESSION['returnURL'])";
        unset($_SESSION['returnURL']);
    } else {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        header('location:home.php');
    }
} else {
    die(header("location:login.php?login-failed=true&reason=not_found"));
}
```

When I replace the contents of `$_SESSION['returnURL']` with the address that is stored in `$_SESSION['returnURL']` it works perfectly.  Something is presenting a problem when I use `$_SESSION['returnURL']` variable with header I think.

Comment: Well you have a syntax error in the first `header` line.

Comment: Can you be specific...I'm not seeing it.  As I mentioned, if I replace my variable with what is actually stored in the session (I am copying and pasting the contents), it works beautifully.  Wouldn't a syntax error throw every time?

Comment: in `header("location:$_SESSION['returnURL'])";` you're missing a closing`)` for the header function. I didn't post an answer because it might just be a typo. Also the answer below addresses your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Problems with this line:

```
header("location:$_SESSION['returnURL'])";
```

Fix the closing bracket:

```
header("location:$_SESSION['returnURL']");
```

And use curly braces for array variables in quoted strings:

```
header("location:{$_SESSION['returnURL']}");
```

Also:

```
htmlspecialchars('/event.php?title=Test&id=16', ENT_QUOTES);
// Results in: /event.php?title=Test&amp;id=16
```

Which is a different URL. You don't need to convert to html entities here.

Comment: I have fixed my typo and added curly braces.  My session['returnURL'] is set, but not recognized.  When I check what sessions are stored, I have:    `Array
(
    [returnURL] => /event-signup.php?title=The%20Seriousness%20of%20Enjoying%20Your%20Group%20Resistances&id=17
)`   When I run the code I always get sent "home.php".  My if statement is failing for some reason.